react-mock-store: TypeError: middleware is not a function
I am using jest with React and Typescript.
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

it("should handle fetchCharacterDataAsync", async () => {
  const characterInitialState = {
    data: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: undefined,
  };
  const store = mockStore(characterInitialState);
  await store.dispatch(fetchCharacterDataAsyncTHUNK("1011334") as any);
});

I am trying to mock the store using react-redux-store and add thunk as a middleware so that I can dispatch thunks from my store.
Following the react-mock-store docs but do not seem to be able to pass in the thunks middleware to the configureStore().  When I do (like I have done above) I get the error:

Type 'typeof import("random_path/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")' is
not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>'.
Type 'typeof import("random_path/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk")'
provides no match for the signature '(api:
MiddlewareAPI<Dispatch, any>): (next: Dispatch)
=> (action: any) => any'.

So to bypass this I am doing this:
const mockStore = configureStore([thunk as any]);
However, this then gives me:

TypeError: middleware is not a function

The docs are here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store
And this should be working as I have followed them right..!?

I suspect you are using the current version 3 of thunk where there is no longer a default export. thunk is a named export in thunk@3.
Import the named thunk export.
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { thunk } from "redux-thunk";

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

it("should handle fetchCharacterDataAsync", async () => {
  const characterInitialState = {
    data: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: undefined,
  };
  const store = mockStore(characterInitialState);
  await store.dispatch(fetchCharacterDataAsyncTHUNK("1011334") as any);
});

That said, using redux-mock-store is actually considered a dated practice these days, you should instead instantiate and use an actual Redux store in your unit tests. The Redux-Toolkit configureStore already includes Thunk middleware enabled by default.
Example:
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { rootReducer } from "../path/to/rootReducer";

it("should handle fetchCharacterDataAsync", async () => {
  const characterInitialState = {
    data: null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: undefined,
  };

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: characterInitialState,
  });

  await store.dispatch(fetchCharacterDataAsyncTHUNK("1011334"));

  // ...assertions
});

